# How to access Developer Portal when Azure API Management is Internal?

Tags: azure-api-management

How to access APIM developer portal from internet when APIM is kept internal?

I checked some Microsoft document but did not get it how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Integrate API Management in an internal VNET with Application Gateway.

Combining API Management provisioned in an internal VNET with the Application Gateway frontend enables the following scenarios:

- Use the same API Management resource for consumption **by both internal
  consumers and external consumers**.
- Use a single API Management resource and have a subset of APIs
  defined in API     Management available for external consumers.
- Provide a turn-key way to switch access to API Management from the
  **public Internet on and off.**

Follow this link for more information : **https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-integrate-internal-vnet-appgateway**